# Морфемный разбор слова

Tags: грамматика

поздравительных

Comment: Ваш вариант?

Answer (score 4):

Не вполне согласна с ответом Виктора. Во-первых, суффикс прилагательного -тельн-. Ведь слово *поздравительный* образовано от слова *поздравить*, а не от *поздравитель*. Во-вторых, исторически, конечно, корень *здрав*/*здоров*. Но сейчас значение слова "поздравить" не обязательно связано со здоровьем, поэтому корень "поздрав". Таким образом, *поздрав-и-тельн-ый.*

Comment: Сколько раз говорили уже: НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ЗА ДЕТЕЙ ДОМАШНИЕ ЗАДАНИЯ, ПОКА ОНИ НЕ ДАДУТ СВОЙ ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА!!

Comment: Не делаю Но не вполне правильный (уже данный) ответ без внимания оставить не могу

Comment: У Потихи "по-здрав-и-тель-н-ый".Видимо, есть разные мнения. По крайней мере, недавно ещё считалось поздравлять-желать здоровья.

Answer (score 0):

Надо, конечно, предлагать свой вариант разбора слова, но если Вам это трудно, то вот как надо ответить: по-здрав-и-тель-н-ых